# A question about the crtp(Curiously Recurring Template Pattern)

Tags: c++, crtp, static-cast

See the code beblow, I have a question about crtp:

- `foo_aa.name_`  is illegal because `foo_aa` is not an object of `class AA`(it is an object of `class Foo<AA>`), it doesn't have a class member called `name_`. I can understand that.
- But I don't understand why `foo_aa.Name()` is legal, because I never define any object of `class AA`, there is no such variable(`name_`) in memory, how does the `Name`function assess variable `name_`?.
- More specifically, I know the cast is made in function `Name`. But I don't understand why the cast is valid, bacause there is only one `Foo<AA>` object and it is just a base class object, how can it be converted to a derived class?

```cpp
namespace static_poly {

template<typename T>
class Foo {
 public:
  std::string Name() {
    return static_cast<T*>(this)->GetName();
  }
};

class AA : public Foo<AA> {
 public:
  std::string GetName() { name_ = "AA"; return name_; }
  std::string name_;
};

void Test() {
  Foo<AA> foo_aa;
  foo_aa.Name();  // legal
  foo_aa.name_ = "hello";  // illagel
}

}  // static_poly
```

According to [Base to derived conversion](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/10518/base-to-derived-conversion), I know a base class object can be converted to a derived class object, but the behavior is undefined, why crtp is ok?

Comment: No, actually it is *not* legal! `foo_aa` is not a `AA` object, thus the `static_cast` fails – though the compiler cannot detect, i.e. you run into undefined behaviour at *rumtime*.

Comment: What works, in contrast, is `AA aa; aa.Name();` – because `AA` inherits from `Foo<AA>` the function `Name` is available – and because `aa` indeed is a `AA` object the `static_cast` is valid.

Comment: And then `aa.name_` would also be valid.

Comment: thank you guys and you are right.  The way I use crtp is not right. I should use class AA instead of Foo<AA>.